# Show totals for "aged away" flags on profile's flag-summary page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flag-history, aged-away

On my profile flag-summary page (aka flag-history), the current flagging history only shows *total flags*, *total helpful*, and *total declined*.
This leaves a gap in the numbers for the ones "*aged away*".

e.g. mine on SO is currently:

**Your flagging history**
154 moderator attention flags
142 deemed helpful
3   declined

142 + 3 = 145
154 - 145 = discrepancy of 9

I have manually counted the "aged away" flags in my history and it is indeed 9.

---

### Suggest

Add "aged away", as follows:

**Your flagging history**
154 moderator attention flags
142 deemed helpful
3   declined
9   aged away

No biggie, but would be nice, and I imagine quite "useful" for those with greater numbers than mine.

Comment: I have three questions trying to revamp the flag-history summary/totals area. The two others are: - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251061/change-flag-summary-page-wording-moderator-attention-flags-to-total-flags - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251068/add-new-titles-spam-and-comments-on-flag-summary-page - I've kept them separate for simplicity, but mostly so people could vote on separate site changes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been completed in the latest build.  The flag history page will now include a stat for aged away.

> [image]