# Change flag-summary page wording "moderator attention flags" to "total flags"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flag-history, wording

On the flag-summary page (aka flag-history), the wording "moderator attention flags" is very misleading, as this total is not "flag for moderator attention", as the name suggests.

It is a total of flags for both the review queue and "direct moderator attention".

I suspect the wording comes from when there were *only* moderators managing flags, and no community reviewing.

**Suggest:** Change wording to "total flags"

**Example:** My *current* flag-history on SO:

**Your flagging history**
154 moderator attention flags
142 deemed helpful
3   declined

I have only ever raised 2 flags to "moderator attention".

**Propose Changing To:**

**Your flagging history**
154 total flags
142 deemed helpful
3   declined

Simple and clear - *total flags*, which already includes total "flags to moderator".

---

I pondered over separating the flags, so "normal" flags and "flags to moderator" separate totals and breakdown. But they're *all* just "flags" to report a problem.

Comment: I have three questions trying to revamp the flag-history summary/totals area. The two others are: - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251048/show-totals-for-aged-away-flags-on-profiles-flag-summary-page  - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251068/add-new-titles-spam-and-comments-on-flag-summary-page - I've kept them separate for simplicity, but mostly so people could vote on separate site changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been done in the latest build.  The history now has category headers of:

- total flags
- spam flags
- offensive flags
- comment flags

and will look like:

> [image]