# Add new titles "Spam" and "Comments" on flag-summary page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flag-history

On the flag-summary page (aka flag-history), currently all the flag totals and history fall under one single title - "Your flagging history".

However, the total flag count ("moderator attention flags") under that title does not include the total counts for "spam" and "comment" flags, which are both listed under the same heading.

**Example:** My *current* flag-history on SO:

**Your flagging history**
154 moderator attention flags
142 deemed helpful
3   declined

6   posts marked spam
5   deemed helpful

7   comments flagged
7   deemed helpful

This *is* all my flagging history, however the total flags ("moderator attention flags") initially appear to also include "spam" and "comment" flags because there is nothing to indicate otherwise.

**Propose Adding Titles:**

**Your flagging history**
154 moderator attention flags
142 deemed helpful
3   declined

**Spam**
6   posts marked spam
5   deemed helpful

**Comments**
7   comments flagged
7   deemed helpful

Comment: I have three questions trying to revamp the flag-history summary/totals area. The two others are: - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251048/show-totals-for-aged-away-flags-on-profiles-flag-summary-page - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251061/change-flag-summary-page-wording-moderator-attention-flags-to-total-flags -  I've kept them separate for simplicity, but mostly so people could vote on separate site changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done in the latest build, there will now be headers for spam flags and comment flags.

> [image]